# How to undo ubuntu upgrade

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, upgrade, amdgpu, recovery-mode

My PC crash during ubuntu upgrade. After rebooting I get the following error message:

kfd kfd amdgpu : Topaz not supported in kfd.

I tried all command lines from recovery mode unfortunately it didn't work.

Is there any solution ? In case where I'm forced to reinstall ubuntu, I won't lose my files

Comment: Based on some googling it appears as you have heimdal installed, but a setting for it that isn't accepted. Try booting into "recovery mode" (google it) and reinstall heimdal?

Comment: You weren't very specific, what type of upgrade (*upgrade of a single package; `apt upgrade`, maybe `apt full-upgrade` or even *release-upgrade*) and didn't specify if you're asking about a 20.04 Desktop or Server install, as you can re-install Ubuntu Desktop (*with few restrictions*) without destruction of files (*you just don't format!*) and have *manually installed* packages (*where from Ubuntu repositories*) auto-reinstall too (*internet needs to be available during install for packages not on ISO*)

Comment: Yes i'm asking about 20.04. The upgrade are done with the ubuntu's software manager. I don't have the access to ubuntu because it won't boot. How can i do it by the recovery mode ? Also I don't have the option "reinstall ubuntu without losing files" when booting by USB.